# Does 'agemates' have a space or not?

Tags: orthography, formality

How is it correctly spelled?

> agemates

or

> age mates

Comment: I'm glad that you used ELU to answer a question of yours, but in this case I think that since your question is answered by a dictionary, this is General Reference. Please don't let this discourage you from asking more questions, though :]

Comment: @simchona Got it. I didn't know about 'General Reference' rules! Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: You're welcome. One thing to be sure to do, in the future, is do a little bit of a lookup. There are some useful references listed [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/list-of-general-references)

Comment: @simchona Thank you, again. And sorry about that `Thanks!` that was in the footer.

Comment: No problem! I'm glad you noticed what I changed, and I look forward to seeing more questions from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Age mate* or  *age-mate*.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/age-mate), and [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/age-mate), and [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/age+mate?s=t) again.

Age-mate seems to be the most popular, according to [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=age+mate%2C+age-mate%2C+agemate&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), and a bit of a 1970s thing.

Comment: Or *agemate*, [actually](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/agemate)

Comment: @simchona Oh, um. Hmm.

Comment: @simchona I'm going to go for `age-mate`. 'Feels' best :)

Comment: @simoncha~ dictionary.com seems to be covering all options..